# Type 'Function & InputTypeComposer<any>[key]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'

Tags: typescript

I want to write a type which can have keys from keys of a class, and if the value of the key is a function, the type's value needs to be equal to the type of the arguments of the function. It may seem complicated, and the explanation is probably not the best, but the code may help:

```js
type Extensions = {
  [key in keyof InputTypeComposer]: InputTypeComposer[key] extends Function
    ? Parameters<InputTypeComposer[key]>
    /*
      Type 'Function & InputTypeComposer<any>[key]' does not satisfy
      the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.ts(2344)
    */
    : never;
};
```

Any suggestions why does it throw the error? Where's the issue?

The type `InputTypeComposer` can be found [here](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose/blob/master/src/InputTypeComposer.d.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the [`Function` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L272-L304) is not declared with a callable signature, although it is possible to call an object of type `Function` as if it were of type `(...args: any) => any`.  If this strikes you as strange, there's an [open issue (microsoft/TypeScript#20007)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007) that you might want to visit and give your .  The explanation there [says](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007#issuecomment-405766256):

> The original intention of `Function` is to not be callable. in other words, `Function` to function types should be like `unknown` to other types, but not callable. we have since relaxed this restriction giving `Function` a callable behavior in the compiler through special casing. We have talked about making this a `--noImplicitAny` error since, it is really unsafe to call `Function`s.

In any case, there's an easy fix here: abandon `Function` in factor of `(...args: any) => any`:

```
type Extensions = {
  [key in keyof InputTypeComposer]: InputTypeComposer[key] extends (...args: any) => any
  ? Parameters<InputTypeComposer[key]>
  : never;
};
```

That should work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBMHtQFwCwKagE4IIYBtYE8AOSBLAOwGcZ1xQCAzUbSAV1AHc0iYBuWOAkqvtqAQAPNAFtcGBAChi5ZNTQBjJAEkiuBjAAqeBAGFIEyCQTJQAb2mhQaAFygiDMQCMzHa6BcAKYQ7LIxADmAJQOAG6QBOAeNkre2A4ukJBSbAA0oABeDk6uZmGgAcGxEEkpaUQeAL7S0jB6oACiwuSkBJCkoAC8lp4A2gDWCNhURKDD9LTqmjp6hsamyAC6DjNauvgLuCZmQyPLQq0IROB83gB0V2jIQSQObNghPQB8tkTYngD8oAAKN+IEPISAAedZzLZGHZLfbYZYvTy5BDhdzSaoeaRAA)